# wordpress list user roles

Tags: wordpress

I am working ion a wordpress project and digging around into roles etc.

I have the following code which basically gets all available roles:

```
<?php 
     global $wp_roles;
     $roles = $wp_roles->get_names();

     // Below code will print the all list of roles.
     print_r($roles);        
?>
```

when i run the above code i get the following output:

```
array ( [administrator] => Administrator [editor] => Editor [author] => Author [contributor] => Contributor [subscriber] => Subscriber [basic_contributor] => Basic Contributor  )
```

i would like the above to be stripped from the array and into just an unordered list. How would i achieve this?

Thanks Dan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop, to loop through each of the roles in the array.

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($roles as $role) { ?>
   <li><?php echo $role;?></li>
<?php }//end foreach ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Here is the code to make dropdown of wordpress user role**

```
<?php global $wp_roles; ?>

<select name="role">
<?php foreach ( $wp_roles->roles as $key=>$value ): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the [l10n functions do not accept variables](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/), [`translate_user_role()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/translate_user_role/) is required to translate the role names properly. Also, using [`wp_roles()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_roles/) rather than the global variable `$wp_roles` is the safer approach, for it first checks if the global is set and if not will set it and return it.

```
$roles = wp_roles()->get_names();

foreach( $roles as $role ) {
    echo translate_user_role( $role );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just an additional information. There's also a function [wp_dropdown_roles()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_roles/) which gives you the roles as option html elements.

```
<select>
   <?php wp_dropdown_roles(); ?>
</select>
```

You can also set the default selected value by passing the role slug as a parameter.

```
<select>
   <?php wp_dropdown_roles( 'editor' ); ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you would like to display a select list of available WordPress role names.

```
$roles_obj = new WP_Roles();
$roles_names_array = $roles_obj->get_names();
echo '<select name="role">';
foreach ($roles_names_array as $role_name) {
    echo '<option>'.$role_name.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Dropdown options, use WordPress native function `wp_dropdown_roles` This will give Translated user roles

Here is the code example

```
<select name="default_role" id="default_role">
    <?php wp_dropdown_roles( get_option( 'default_role' ) ); ?>
</select>
```